# Best way to speed up multiple uses of "CGContextDrawRadialGradient" in drawrect?

Tags: performance, calayer, gradient, cglayer, radial

I couldn't post the image, but I use the "CGContextDrawRadialGradient" method to draw a shaded blue ball (~40 pixel diameter), it's shadow and to make a "pulsing" white ring around the ball (inner and outer gradients on the ring).  The ring starts at the edges of the blue ball and expands outward (radius grows with a timer).  The white ring fades as it expands outward like a radio wave.

Looks great running in the simulator but runs incredibly slow on the iPhone 4.  The ring should pulse in about a second (as in simulator), but takes 15-20 seconds on the phone.  I have been reading a little about CALayer, CGLayer and reading some segments on a some gradient animation, but it isn't clear what I should be using for best performance.

How do I speed this up.  Should I put the ball on a layer and the expanding ring on another layer?  If so, how do I know which layer to update on a drawrect?

Appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to speed something like that up is to pre-render it. Determine how many image frames you need to make it look good and then draw each frame into a context you created with CGBitmapContextCreate and capture the image using CGBitmapContextCreateImage. Probably the easiest way to animate the images would be to set the animationImages property of a UIImageView (although there are other options, like CALayer animations).

The newest Apple docs finally mention which pixel formats are supported in iOS so make sure to [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE) those when creating your bitmap context.